# Rails form_tag row fields are too large

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Using Rails 4 and Bootstrap 3.

I've got what should be a basic login form.  However, I cannot get it to format well on any device.  On smaller devices, it's unusable.  Diagnosing that, I believe that the right margin of the rows are huge.  However, I cannot determine what is causing that problem.

I know that the whole form has become unnecessarily complex.  Most of that complexity was just my effort to make it usable.  I will simplify it once this problem is resolved, I guess.

I am working on my HTML and, especially, CSS knowledge.  I use Firebug.  Any advice on how I can work this out in the future would be appreciated.  All help appreciated, actually.

The form when it is in a usable size is:
[image]

This is a view of the form showing the div that should contain the rows:
[image]

This is a view of the rows.  The right margin is huge and I haven't found an element where I can change it:
[image]

This is the Rails view of the form:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <h1>Log in</h1>
  <%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="field align_right">
          <%= label_tag :logon %>
          <%= text_field_tag :logon %>
        </div>
        <div class="break_line"></div>
        <div class="field align_right">
          <%= label_tag :password %>
          <%= password_field_tag :password %>
        </div>
        <div class="break_line"></div>
        <div class="field align_right">
          <%= label_tag :remember_me %>
          <%= check_box_tag :remember_me, 1, true %>
        </div>
        <div class="break_line"></div>
        <div class="field align_right">
          <%= label_tag :change_password %>
          <%= check_box_tag :change_password, nil, false %>
        </div>
        <div class="break_line"></div>
        <div class="field align_right never" id="new_password_div">
          <%= label_tag :new_password %>
          <%= password_field_tag :new_password %>
        </div>
        <div class="break_line"></div>
        <div class="field align_right never" id="password_confirmation_div">
          <%= label_tag :confirmation %>
          <%= password_field_tag :password_confirmation %>
        </div>
        <div class="break_line"></div>
        <div class="actions"><%= submit_tag "Log in" %></div>
      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And this is the form as HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/sessions" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8"><input type="hidden" value="...=" name="authenticity_token"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="field align_right">
          <label for="logon">Logon</label>
          <input type="text" name="logon" id="logon" style="background-image: url(&quot;...&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-position: right center;">
        </div>
        <div class="break_line"></div>
        <div class="field align_right">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" style="background-image: url(&quot;...&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-position: right center;">
        </div>
        <div class="break_line"></div>
        <div class="field align_right">
          <label for="remember_me">Remember me</label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="remember_me" id="remember_me" checked="checked">
        </div>
        <div class="break_line"></div>
        <div class="field align_right">
          <label for="change_password">Change password</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="change_password" id="change_password">
        </div>
        <div class="break_line"></div>
        <div id="new_password_div" class="field align_right never">
          <label for="new_password">New password</label>
          <input type="password" name="new_password" id="new_password" style="background-image: url(&quot;...&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-position: right center;">
        </div>
        <div class="break_line"></div>
        <div id="password_confirmation_div" class="field align_right never">
          <label for="confirmation">Confirmation</label>
          <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" style="background-image: url(&quot;...&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-position: right center;">
        </div>
        <div class="break_line"></div>
        <div class="actions"><input type="submit" value="Log in" name="commit"></div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply had a margin-right override in effect that I could not locate.  I need to keep working those debuggers.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the correct Bootstrap 3 form and field classes.

Here is the code sample for [bootstrap horizontal forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) which seems to be what you're modeling your form after.

Comment: I appreciate the response. It might help.  But, if anything, it leaves me more confused.  What are the parameters of the "correct form and field classes"?  And, what makes what I am doing incorrect?

Comment: Actually, never mind.  I've never understood Bootstrap to be anything more than a collection of classes and helpers.  Reviewing your link in this context clears that up.  It's a highly stylized design platform.  That makes me like it even less, but no big deal.  Let me see if I can make this work...

Comment: Bootstrap is intended for quickly prototyping views. None of the front-end/css frameworks are really for production use, although most people use them in production. The answer has been updated to use the correct class names.

Comment: That's interesting!  Having a bit of trouble finalizing this.  Don't think it's a separate question but say so if so.  I am trying to enable a checkbox by default and cannot find that option yet.  More generally, I am seeing indications that styling is often done using ID instead of Class.  I control the forms using JavaScript and that's a conflict.  What am I missing?  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: As an aside, my Bootstrap efforts have mainly stemmed from integration with DataTables and SimpleForms.  This may be the only native form I have with inputs.  I guess that's the cause of my confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I cannot go in this direction.  On top of all else, RubyMine doesn't recognize the Bootstrap elements for breakpoints.  I wondered where I got the original code I was using and it comes from Sorcery.  I'll have to see if I can fix that.  Thanks.